# Paradoxes and inconsistent set of sentences

Tags: logic, paradox

Let's define logic as:
A statement and it's opposite, obtained by applying the "not" operator, both cannot be true. The not operator is applied to the part of the sentence describing action or attribute.
Example:
a) The apple is red. The apple is not red.
b) Swamy crossed over the fence. Swamy did not cross over the fence.

If in a set of statements, there exist two statements which are both true, and are opposites, then the set is inconsistent.

Do all paradoxes fall under the set of inconsistent statements or set of statements?
(Assuming of course that I have reasonably and objectively defined "logic", and other terms).

Comment: The way classical 1st-order logic works, it *follows* that **p** and ¬**p** can’t both be true. “The not operator is applied to the part of the sentence describing action or attribute”: compare ∃xPx and ∃x¬Px. Negation is applied to the predicate, but the sentences *can* both be true. “in a set of statements, there exist two statements which are both true, and are opposites”. If 'opposites' = **p** and ¬**p**, then they *can’t* both be true, by your earlier definition. So, I think you need to revise your definitions a little before we can answer the question.

Comment: @MarkOxford : Can every sentence in natural language be converted into first order logic form? Why is my definition wrong? If two statements exists which are both true and opposites, then they are inconsistent.

Comment: Some natural-language sentences are easier to translate than other. E.g. ‘John runs’ is easy, while ‘Jack and Jill have a son’ is harder. (It’s not just ‘Jack has a son and Jill has a son’: they have a son *together*.) Or take: ‘Earth is a small planet’, which is not: ‘Earth is small and a planet’. Some sentence cannot be translated into FOL, such as sentences that quantify over properties and relations: ‘Jack and Jill have something in common’ might be an example. (See the Geach-Kaplan sentence for a (much) more complicated example.)

Comment: As for your definition: are the two statements both true, or are they opposites? As you say yourself, if they are opposites, they can’t both be true.

Comment: @MarkOxford : Thanks. I'm trying to define "Inconsistent". If they are opposites and true then the set breaks logic and is Inconsistent.

Comment: There are two definitions of inconsistency: A set S is *semantically* inconsistent iff there is no way to make all the sentences in S true simultaneously. (‘no way to make true simultaneously’ is then spelt out in terms of semantic structures, as ‘there is no structure that makes them all true.) A set S is *syntactically* inconsistent iff for all sentences *s*, there is a proof from S to *s*. This is harder to see, but remember the law *ex falso quodlibet*: anything follows from a contradiction. Note that a set is semantically inconsistent iff it is syntactically inconsistent.

Comment: I think Aristotle would apply the 'not' operator to the copula, not to the action or attribute. I'd agree with Mark that if two statements form a legitimate contradictory pair then they cannot both be true since if they were they would not qualify as a contradictory pair. Right here is the trick of resolving metaphysical dilemmas.

Comment: You have not defined "logic"; you have stated the [Principle of bivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence) as well as the [Law of noncontradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction), two basic principles of classical logic, due to Aristotle.

Comment: A [Pardox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox) in philosophy is not simply a *contradiction* : "A paradox is a statement that, despite apparently sound reasoning from true premises, leads to an apparently self-contradictory or logically unacceptable conclusion."

Comment: "If in a set of statements, there exist two statements which are both true, and are opposites, then the set is inconsistent." If we stay to the principles above, two opposite sentences cannot be both true.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - I share your view, or almost. You say that a  paradox in philosophy is not simply a contradiction. I would say it is not even a contradiction. But I'm still pondering.  :

Comment: You are not aware that opposite is a bad term to use in logic. The not operarator does not show you that contrary relationships can exist. Contrary relationships express BOTH claims cannot be true simultaneously BUT BOTH claims can be FALSE simultaneously. So the term inconsistent expresses only that the truth values of the claims in question are not equivalent.

Comment: @novice Did you have a specific paradox in mind when you thought of this question? Was there a logic puzzle, for example, that brought this to mind? If so, what was this original pair of statements?

Comment: By the way. the rule is not simply that A and not-A cannot both be true, but that one must be true and one false. If this is not the case then the LEM and LNC do  not apply.;So where A and not-A are both true or both false this is not a legitimate contradictory pair and no paradox is implied.  .  .   .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer above said: no paradox is ever an inconsistent set of statements.

I disagree.

Proof:

**The next statement is true.**

**The previous statement is false.**

The examples in the author's question are not actually paradoxes but sentences with no relation to each other.

In my example, you have yourself the actual paradox (loop-type).

Answer (score 0):

First, 'logic' is far broader than inconsistency. You are just trying to capture inconsistency, not all of logic.

Second, there are ways to obtain an inconsistent set of statements other than there being a statement and its negation in the set. For example, the set {P, P->Q, ~Q} is inconsistent, but does not explicitly contain a statement and its negation.

This is why inconsistency is typically defined in terms of truth-assignments: if there is no possible truth-assignment (obeying the truth-functional constraints for the truth-functional operators as we typically define them) such that all statements in the set are true, then the set is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

A paradox is an argument for which logic does not determine whether it is true or false, but which seems to be properly formed and meaningful.

An inconsistent set of statements taken together contains a contradiction.  So it must be false.

Therefore it has already been determined whether it is true or false.

So no paradox is *ever* an inconsistent set of statements.